# Spring REST 3 and JacksonMapper for JSON

Tags: web-services, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

We are currently using spring web services that support application/xml and application/json that works fine. A new service requires returning of an XML string. The string must be kept as XML but I find that application/json is also serializing the contents of the string. Is there any way to prevent this ?

Edits:

```
//dto:
@XmlRootElement(name="mydata")
public class MyData {
    private String someData;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String content;
    @XmlElement
    public String getSomeData(){
         return someData;
    }
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
}
   //setter and other fields...
}
```

From the above, the content field is an XML string in my class. I would like the content field to be returned but not serialized. Is this possible ?

Comment: what do you mean by 'returned but not serialized' exactly? Could you show us sample output (with content type) that you want to get from controller?

Comment: @Adam Jurczyk. The "content" string contains an XML string that is currently been converted to JSON. I would like the string to stay in XML format.

Comment: this is strange ^^ So, you say that whole ``MyData`` is serialized as XML, but content (already serialized to XML) is converted to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return XML, then add this annotation to the service:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "xyz", headers = "Accept=application/xml")
```

Comment: Thanks. My question may be more difficult to understand. I do not want to always return XML, I only want to limit one field of my returned object to be XML. Question edited to reflect.

Comment: avoid using setter and getter methods on fields for which you don't want conversion to happen, it's working for me

Comment: Now, I got your question. I think it's not possible to return both versions of data-marshaled and plan, in one go.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I could'nt see an easy way, JsonIgnore will leave it out, i had hoped that there was a way or another annotation that would just not serialise the field.

Comment: But, using @JsonIgnore means, you won't be able to get the plan data because what you get is the serialized version. Your requirement is to get a field which is not serialized, yet you want to access it, I suppose ?

Answer (score 0):

If this string is just serialized object (just like JSON with `@ResponseBody`), than everything you need is `jackson-jaxrs` lib and marking return bean with `javax.xml.bind.annotation.*` annotations:

```java
//in controller:
@RequestMapping
public @ResponseBody MyData getMyData(){
    MyData md = new MyData();
    //...
    return md;
}

//dto:
@XmlRootElement(name="mydata")
public class MyData {
    private String someData;
    @XmlElement
    public String getSomeData(){
         return someData;
    }
    //setter and other fields...
}
```

Comment: thanks. I've edited the main question with your sample code to reflect what it is I am trying to achieve.